# tail recursive implementation of a factorial function

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion, factorial

I am reading the book by jason and do not quite understand the following program:

```
let fact2 i =
    let rec loop accum i =
        if i = 0 then 
            accum
        else
            loop (i * accum) (i - 1)
    in
        loop 1
```

1. How is accum initialized?
2. What is the meaning of the last two lines (i.e. in loop 1)? loop has two parameters. why only one is passed here (i.e. loop 1).

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're confusion is probably a result of the fact the function is wrong. You're correct that the last line should be called with two arguments, it should be `loop 1 i`.

Comment: In OCaml, variables are not initialized because they are immutable (the name variable is misleading, they are just named values).

Answer (score 5):

I think that it's a mistake in implementation. Last line should be

> loop 1 i

Integer 1 initialises `accum` from `loop` function and `i` initializes `i` in the same function.

Comment: Thank you!! helps a lot. But I still do not quite understand the last two lines. What're their functions here? Yes, I have a problem with understanding nested functions. Does it mean what after "in" is the value of the let expression? That is, loop 1 i is just the value of fact2?

Comment: In OCaml last expression in function body is its result. i.e. 'loop 1 i' is result of 'fact2 i'.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the lines starting with `let rec loop accum i` define a *function*. So `accum` is initialized when the function is called. This happens in the last line. As Kakadu points out, there's a transcription error in your post. The last line should say `loop 1 i` which (in essence) initializes `accum` to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an extra "i" in the first line. That makes fact2 take an extra argument which is never used. Instead it should read:

```
let fact2 =
```

The last line that says "loop 1" is often called a partial application.

Ocaml usually uses curried functions, so another way of thinking of it is that `loop` actually takes one parameter and returns a function which in turn takes another parameter and returns an int.

In this particualar case, the type of `(loop 1)` is `int -> int` meaning it takes an `int` and returns an `int`. The type of `loop` is `int -> int -> int` meaning it takes an `int` and return an `int -> int`. It can also be written more explicitly as `int -> (int -> int)` since `->` is right-associative.

To answer the other question, `accum` is initialized by passing 1 to `loop`.

Here is more information on currying: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

And of course, adding another "i" as others are suggesting would also work, but then you'd still be confused when others left it out.

It may help to think of `let f x y = ...` as being equivalent to `let f = fun x -> fun y -> ...`

And of course `let f x = g x` is the same as `let f = g` except the former will only work when `g` is a function.

Comment: Yes. you are right I have a problem with understanding nested functions. Based on your explanation, I think I understand the theory, but I still do not understand some examples. Here is another example to check whether I understand it well:
let sum i =

Comment: let sum i = 
            let sum2 j = i + j 
            in sum2;;

Here, the type of sum2 is int->int. sum i is another function takes int. Then we have int->(int->int) for sum?

Comment: Yes, looks like you understand that example.